# Is there a formula to increment by 1, but in a binary way, in Excel, and then repeat the pattern?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to do the following: excel excerpt

[image]

but when I drag the numbers down in excel, it just increments from %IX0.7 onwards, so if I drag after %IX1.0 onwards, it will appear %IX1.0 then %IX0.8, %IX0.9, ...

Is there a way to easily do this? The only way I'm seeing is manually increment the first number every 8 cells then drag 8 down and repeat.

Comment: Try using this formula, `="%|X"&TEXT(INT(SEQUENCE(24,,0,1/8))+MOD(SEQUENCE(24)-1,8)/10,"0.0")`

Comment: If you're not using Office 365 / Excel 2021 then you can use ="%|X"&INT((ROW()-1)/8)&"."&MOD(ROW()-1,8)  assuming you want the results to start in row 1

Answer (score 2):

The numbering system you want is called "Octal".  Excel provides several functions to convert decimal numbers to octal: `DEC2OCT` and `BASE`

When using Excel365, you can create a Spill formula to create the whole column, no need to drag down.

You can also hard code the first address and number of addresses to return, or enter those into other cells

The formula:

```
=LET(AddrAsOct,BASE(SEQUENCE(17,1,0,1),8,2),"%IX"&LEFT(AddrAsOct,1)&"."&RIGHT(AddrAsOct,1))
```

Or, using references

```
=LET(AddrAsOct,BASE(SEQUENCE(B2,1,B1,1),8,2),Prefix,B3,Prefix&LEFT(AddrAsOct,1)&"."&RIGHT(AddrAsOct,1))
```

Demo (formula in cell `B5` spills, no drag down required)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This formula will produce the output you request:

```
=TEXT(DEC2OCT(ROW()-1),"""%""IX0"".""0")
```

`ROW()` can be adjusted according to actual number, for example if your formula should start on row 3, use `ROW()-3` to get the initial value of %IX0.0

the formula uses a combination of `DEC2OCT` which converts number to octal numbers and `TEXT` that provides the extra letters in addition to the numbers, the % and . needs to be in quotes which are written as `""` for each quote in a formula

Comment: To start at `%IX:0.0` as per OPs sample, you'll need `=TEXT(DEC2OCT(ROW()-1),"""%""IX0"".""0")`

Comment: And the formula can be made to spill: `=TEXT(DEC2OCT(ROW(E1:E17)-1),"""%""IX0"".""0")`

Comment: You can also use `SEQUENCE` to generate the decimal addresses here: `=TEXT(DEC2OCT(SEQUENCE(B2,1,B1,1)),"""%""IX0"".""0")` (using the data in my answer as start and number od address) (great answer btw - much better than mine)

Comment: Thanks @chris , nice addition with the sequence. I'll keep the answer as the OP wanted to drag down. this will work as well: `=TEXT(DEC2OCT(SEQUENCE(24)-1),"""%""IX0"".""0")`

Comment: Maybe OP doesn't know about Spill, or isn't useing 365

Answer (score 1):

You may ***try*** any ***one*** of the either,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

---

• For **All Versions** Of Excel,

```
="%|X"&TEXT(INT((ROW()-2)/8)+MOD(ROW()-2,8)/10,"0.0")
```

---

• For **Excel 2021** & **O365** Users,

```
="%|X"&TEXT(INT(SEQUENCE(24,,0,1/8))+MOD(SEQUENCE(24)-1,8)/10,"0.0")
```

Or, Using **`LET()`** Function

```
=LET(A,8,B,24,"%|X"&TEXT(INT(SEQUENCE(B,,0,1/A))+MOD(SEQUENCE(B)-1,A)/10,"0.0"))
```

---

Use a **`LAMBDA()`** Function to create a custom, reusable function and refer them by a friendly name, --> Applicable To Only **O365 Exclusively**!

```
=BINARY(A,B)
```

Where,

```
BINARY =LAMBDA(A,B,"%|X"&TEXT(INT(SEQUENCE(B,,0,1/A))+MOD(SEQUENCE(B)-1,A)/10,"0.0"))
```

**`LAMBDA()`** Function used in **Name Manager** with a **Defined Name** as `BINARY` with syntax as

```
=BINARY(A,B) --> =BINARY(8,24)
```

**Where 24 Rows Repeated, 8 is incremented from 0 to 7**

Answer (score 0):

If you would like the actual numbers underlying the list to be the value they seem to have, you can use:

```
="%IX"  &  TEXT(  VALUE(  DEC2OCT(  SEQUENCE(22,1,0,1)  )  )/10,  "0.0")
```

`SEQUENCE` generates a set of values (and one can substitute the older `ROW` technique if one does not have `SEQUENCE`). `DEC2OCT` then makes the change to octal, and also to a set of strings. At this point, values like 18 are permanently gone going forward. `VALUE` now changes them back to actually being decimal numbers, but you still have the gaps desire, like no 8 or 9 between 7 and 10.

Those are made to be a list of values one tenth the integer values by dividing by 10, which works because `VALUE` change them back. Again, the gaps will remain. Finally, the union operator at the beginning will prepend the `%IX` and change the values back to text using the format `0.0`.

[This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72082544/10871073) has a very slick formula in which the underlying values are integers and remain so. So even though you have a list like 1, 2, 3, etc., it displays as 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, etc. If you do not need, or find useful, the list to really be the 0.1, 0.2, etc., that formula is shorter and very slick. But if you need, or it would be handy to have, the list and the underlying values to be what is displayed, this formula will do that.